# Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1 missing windows.h

Tags: visual-studio

I am attempting to compile a `.cpp` file on Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1 and the file `windows.h` is not present on the system. What do I have to do to make this file available to Visual Studio? The file being compiled contains `include <windows.h>`.

Comment: Open VS installer and see if you have C++ for Windows enabled. You should also enable Windows SDK, though the installer should automatically choose a default version for you.

Comment: @Lex My installer does not show either component. Where should I find them, in Workloads or Individual Components?

Comment: Under "Workloads" you must check "Desktop development with C++". In its "Installation details" you can see "Windows 10 SDK" selected under "Optional". That's how all necessary header files are installed on your machine.

Comment: @Lex I have Desktop development with C++ installed but there is no sign of windows.h Which SDK do I need to have installed?

Comment: "Lex It turns out that the Windows 10 SDK was not installed. I am Installing iy now and will check my environment.

Comment: @Lex downloading the Windows 10 SDK only gave me windows.h in the X86 directory. I am working with existing software. Is it possible that the program I am working on is actually 32 bits but thinks it is 64 bits?

Comment: @lLex it turns out that the application needed a specific version of the Windows 10 SDK, Downloading that fixed everything. If you  turn this into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`windows.h` usually comes from Windows SDK installation. Like you discovered, some projects might even require a certain version of Windows SDK. Therefore, when such compilation errors happen, the first thing to do is to read carefully the source code documentation, which might indicate what is needed to install in advance.

Visual Studio 2017/2019 become more modular than previous releases, so missing a component is expected, and you can always go back to VS installer to find the suitable components to install.

Comment: I found out what version was needed by checking the project properties in Solution Explorer.