# windows.h in c++ clr forms application using visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, forms

i try to include the "Windows.h" header in the windows forms c++ extension from visual studio 2019 (Community Edition) but if i try to include this ("Windows.h"), there are dozens of errors - all with the message like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(292,19): error C4430:" ... without it works correct ... maybe you know the solution.

Comment: I believe you need to install Windows SDK ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243414/visual-studio-2019-preview-1-missing-windows-h )

Comment: You should probably include what the actual error message is. C4430 isn't helpful, unless you expect us to look it up for you

Comment: yes i think its because the sdk - but the paths are correct set ... but once again its just at the win forms c++ extension for visual studio 2019 - maybe someone could try - i think he will get the same error ...

Comment: ok ... i dont know exactly why - but after make a new c++ win forms application - it works :)