# Cannot open header files (VS2019)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

```
#pragma once;

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    printf("Some text \n");
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with the errors:
[image]

I recently installed VS2019 on my PC with Windows 7.

Comment: Where are those headers on your disk? How exactly are you trying to build? Make? Project config? Search paths?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the corresponding `windows sdk` with the visual studio installer [(see also this SO Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243414/visual-studio-2019-preview-1-missing-windows-h/54299490#54299490). The sdk for windows 7 can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8442). Don't forget to set the `platform toolset` to use the windows 7 sdk in your project config. A guide can be found [here](https://allenkuo.medium.com/visual-studio-2019-2017-works-with-win-sdk-7-1-7a41443e425b).